# Highcharts TypeScript - Property 'RangeSelector' does not exist on type 'typeof import'

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I want to prototype the drawInput Highcharts function in TypeScript and when I want to do:

```
(function (H) {
    Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.drawInput = () => {
        // some code
    };
})(Highcharts);
```

it says that "Property 'RangeSelector' does not exist on type 'typeof import'"

I tried to do the following:

```
(function (H) {
    console.log(Highcharts.RangeSelector)
})(Highcharts as any);
```

and it returned undefined. Strange is that when I simply do the

```
console.log(Highcharts)
```

it shows the RangeSelector option

Comment: It's not enough if you do it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-typescript-rangeselector-68zhz2?

Comment: @Michał Sorry, I didn't see your answer earlier. Yes, that helped! Thanks a lot!
Now I got different problem but that's with TypeScript itselt so this question is solved ;)
Maybe add this in answer so I can pick best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the Highcharts object as any:

```
(function (H) {
  console.log((H as any).RangeSelector);
  (H as any).RangeSelector.prototype.drawInput = () => {
    // some code
  };
})(Highcharts);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-typescript-rangeselector-68zhz2